# How to rotate text in 90 degree and fit with the page height?

Tags: rotating

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.5cm,top=0.4cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\minicontent}{\foreach \x in {প্লেট,সসপেন(ঢাকনাসহ) \hfill সেট,বাটি/বোল,ভাত বাড়ার ছোট প্লেট,বন প্লেট,গ্লাস,হামান দিস্তা,চাকু,আলু ছেলার কাটার,বালতি,জগ,মগ,দস্তরখানা,চামচ,বটি,ঘুটনি,লুস্নি,দড়ি(রং সহ),বাজারের ব্যাগ,চুলা,সিলিন্ডার}{\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{
\noindent
\multido{}{3}{\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}\minicontent\vspace{2cm}\end{minipage}
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output shows that there was large space unused bellow of the page. When I use `0.33\textheight` instead of `0.33\textwidth` the lower text is in about to cut and make 2 pages although one page has no content.

[image]

Or, is there any solution or package that provide such a environment so that I can consider `textwidth` as `textheight` and write as normal scenario and the package automatically convert the text alongside the height.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can get landscape orientation for the full document either by adding the `lansdscape` option to the LaTeX document classes, i.e.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
```

or by loading the `geometry` package with its `landscape` option.  This also allows you to set `textwidth=` and `textheight=`, or change the margins of the page.

```
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
```

If you want to change only part of the document, you can use the `lscape` package, which provides `\begin{landscape}` ... `\end{landscape}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You can change both `textwidth` and `textheight` using `geometry`.

Comment: Is these correct in Landscape `land.textwidth=normal textheight` and `land.textheight=normal textwidth`?

Comment: Sorry, using \begin{landscape} changes `\textheight` and `\linewidth`, but not `\textwidth`.  (One can test for landscape using `\ifdim\textwidth=\textheight`)